# SQL: retrieve unique structure

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having trouble finding exclusive group data set for the given query paramter.

My table is like this:

```
GROUP_ID  DOMAIN_ID (unique)
--------  ---------
111       2123
111       2124
111       2125
111       2126
112       2124
112       2125
113       2124
113       2125
113       2126
114       2124
114       2127
114       2128
```

Ok, now I need to find a GROUP_ID where DOMAIN_ID **ONLY** contains **2124** and **2125** i.e. it should not return 111 or 113 from the example above.

Limitation: Can't use SP/Function. It should be one SQL query.

Thanks very much for your time in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the [relational operator you require is divide](http://www.dbdebunk.com/page/page/772076.htm) a.k.a. "the supplier who supplies all parts". Do you want divide with or without remainder i.e. can  the supplier supply parts in addition to the ones requested? How to handle the empty set i.e. if the set of parts to supply is empty, can all suppliers supply or is it more useful to return no suppliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for responding to my question.

Finally, I managed to write a query which gives me the result I wanted:

```
select GROUP_ID
from MY_TABLE oq
where DOMAIN_ID  in (2124, 2125)
group by GROUP_ID
having count(GROUP_ID)=2 and 
count(GROUP_ID) = (select count(iq.DOMAIN_ID) 
from MY_TABLE iq WHERE iq.GROUP_ID=oq.GROUP_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you group by groupid you can use the HAVING clause to look for the group whose min(domainid) =2124 and max(domainid)=2125

Comment: I cant use number function becase domain_id contains alphanumeric. I only want GROUP_ID which only contains the requested domain_id set.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT group_id FROM table WHERE group_id IN (SELECT group_id FROM table WHERE domain_id in (2124, 2124)) GROUP BY group_id HAVING count(group_id) = 2;
```

The benefit with this approach is that the two domain_ids don't need to be sequential as in one of the other answers.

Using your data in sqlite3, this produces:

```
sqlite> create table t (a int, b int);
sqlite> .import data t
sqlite> SELECT a FROM t WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM t WHERE b in (2124, 2124)) GROUP BY a HAVING count(a) = 2;
a
112
```

Comment: I just tried with sqlite and it worked well. Is it returning too many records for you?

Comment: Thx Steve, but this won't help becuase the query itself is wrong. Try with the large data set and verify the result set. You will notice that there are many group ids which have specified param values but also other values.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```
SELECT DOMAIN_ID, COUNT(*) AS OCCURRENCES FROM TEST WHERE DOMAIN_ID = '2124' OR DOMAIN_ID =     '2125' GROUP BY DOMAIN_ID
```

results in:

```
DOMAIN_ID   OCCURRENCES     2124        4
2125        3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have (group_id,domain_id) duplicates you can use

```
SELECT group_id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN domain_id=2124 OR domain_id=2125 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS matches 
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY group_id
HAVING matches=2
```

Comment: Works fine on your example, works fine on big set of random data. On what data it failed for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_ID
FROM atable
GROUP BY GROUP_ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN DOMAIN_ID IN (2124, 2125) THEN 1 END) = 2
   AND COUNT(*) = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_ID FROM TABLE
WHERE DOMAIN_ID IN (2124, 2125)
```

Something like this?

Comment: As I said I only need GROUP_ID which only contains this data set. ypur solution give me 111,112 and 113. If it was that simple I would not have asked. :)

Comment: That will select groups that have 2124, 2125 and 2123.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the question. I will leave this answer up to help clarify your real question.